# useraction parameter in URL

Tags: paypal

> Please some one explain what happens if we send **useraction=commit** in paypal  site url.

```
> And what parameters we need to send to paypal in SetExpress checkout request to make visible purchase value at PayPal site page.
```

Answer (score 1):

With Express Checkout, you can shorten your checkout flow to let buyers complete their
purchases on PayPal. Then, you can skip your order confirmation page.

Generally, buyers select payment methods as the last step before they complete their
purchases. If you collect no additional information after buyers return from PayPal, you can
skip the confirm-order page on your website. If you collect additional information that does
not affect the payment, PayPal recommends that you collect it after buyers complete their
purchases.

The useraction URL parameter in your redirect to PayPal determines whether buyers
complete their purchases on PayPal or on your website. If you set useraction to commit,
PayPal sets the button text to Pay Now on the PayPal Review your informaton page. This
text lets buyers know that they complete their purchases if they click the button.

As for your other question about what parameters you need to send to PayPal in SetExpressCheckout request to make visible purchase value at PayPal site page, I am not sure I completely understand what you are asking.  If you pass over the amount, this will show up on the checkout page.  If you are wanting items to show up on these pages, you would need to pass over the line item details.  These variables can be found in the Express Checkout Developers Guide, they will be slightly different depending on if you are using SOAP or NVP.

[NVP Developers Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf)

[SOAP Developers Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_api_reference.pdf)